# Why does this procedure run in MYSQL but not in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures

I'm new to Java and struggling a bit.

I've set up a procedure in mysql to return employee details when the last name is entered:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getEmployeeByLastName(IN in_last_name VARCHAR(16))
SELECT emp_no, first_name, last_name, gender, hire_date FROM oop_employees
WHERE last_name = in_last_name;
```

This works in phpmyadmin when I execute it.

In my Java main method I ask a user to enter a last name...

```
System.out.println("Please enter the last name of the employee.");
String last_name = keyboard.next();
Employee emp = getEmployeeByLastName(dbc.getConnection(), last_name);           
System.out.println(emp);
```

`getEmployeeByLastName` is:

```
public static Employee getEmployeeByLastName(Connection conn, String lname) {
    Employee emp = null;
    try {
        String sql = "CALL getEmployeeByLastName(\""+ lname +"\")";
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);     
        while (rs.next())       
            emp = new Employee(rs.getInt("emp_no"), rs.getDate("birth_date"),rs.getString("first_name"),rs.getString("last_name"), rs.getString("gender"),rs.getDate("hire_date"));
            rs.close(); 
            st.close(); 
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return emp;
}
```

When I search for a last name I get several SQL exception errors, and two errors in the code above:

```
emp = new Employee(rs.getInt("emp_no"), rs.getDate("birth_date"),rs.getString("first_name"),rs.getString("last_name"), rs.getString("gender"),rs.getDate("hire_date"));
```

and..

```
Employee emp = getEmployeeByLastName(dbc.getConnection(), last_name);
```

I was able to create other procedures that displayed data from the database using the employee class, this is my first procedure where user input is required.

Is there an obvious reason why this is working in mysql but not in eclipse? All help greatly appreciated, I'm finding this very hard to debug. Please let me know if more information is required.

EDIT:

**Exceptions**

```
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:959)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:862)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1076)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getDate(ResultSetImpl.java:2034)
```

Comment: What are the exceptions ? Post the minimal stacktrace

Comment: Include exceptions in your question

Comment: `rs.getDate("birth_date")` - I don't know if that's the only error, but your procedure is not fetching that column.

Comment: Do you mean the exception number?

Comment: I mean what type of exceptions do you get ?

Comment: I've updated the question to include exceptions.

Comment: `rs.getDate("birth_date")` , `rs.getDate("hire_date")` try getting these dates as strings. `rs.getString("birth_date")` , `rs.getString("hire_date")`

Comment: It's expecting date format from my constructor. Also, the database columns are in date format. If I change to getString the line shows an error.

Comment: @Eran Thank you very much, that is exactly what the problem was.

Comment: @ovokuro You're welcome. I posted the comment as an answer.

Comment: Just curious...Why even use a procedure for the way you're using it? Why not just pass the SQL query string as a parameter for the getEmployeeByLastName() method since it is just returning specific data anyways? I can understand it if your method was returning a **result set** so you can pull out and process the data you want after the method call. This way the process can be used for any query.

Comment: @DevilsHnd Thanks for comment, I'm new to procedures (and Java), so not entirely sure of when to use a procedure. Are there no benefits to using one in this case? I'm also unsure if the method I'm doing it is secure enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query selects 5 columns from your `oop_employees` table :

```
SELECT emp_no, first_name, last_name, gender, hire_date FROM oop_employees
```

But your Java code attempts to read 6 columns from the `ResultSet` :

```
emp = new Employee(rs.getInt("emp_no"), rs.getDate("birth_date"),rs.getString("first_name"),rs.getString("last_name"), rs.getString("gender"),rs.getDate("hire_date"));
```

You forgot to include the `birth_date` column in your SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

This issue because the JDBC code cannot parse the resultset. The procedure is fine, but the Java code needs to be fixed. There is a difference between the SQL and the Resultset. As the other commentator (@Eran) has pointed out, you are only selecting 5 columns in the SQL.

```
SELECT emp_no, first_name, last_name, gender, hire_date FROM oop_employees WHERE last_name = in_last_name;
```

But you are expecting the result set to look for 6 columns.

```
emp = new Employee(rs.getInt("emp_no"), rs.getDate("birth_date"),rs.getString("first_name"),rs.getString("last_name"), rs.getString("gender"),rs.getDate("hire_date"));
```

Add the "birth_date" column in the SQL and try again.

Also please paste the full stack trace when you post a question. The stack trace you have given is incomplete.